# Get indices for sorted permutation of an array in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, arrays, sorting, enumerable

Let's say I have an Array `ary = [0.0, 1.0, 5.0, 1.0, -2.0, 3.5]`, and I want as output another array of the same size containing `ary`'s indices in sorted-by-value-order. In other words, the output should be `[4,0,1,3,5,2]`. Is there an efficient way to do this with `Enumerable` or `Array`?

The most trivial solution I can imagine is as follows:

```
class Array
  def sorted_indices
    self.map.with_index{ |v,i| [v,i] }.sort{ |a,b| a[0] <=> b[0] }.map { |v| v[1] }
  end
end
```

but I feel like there has to be something simpler already built in.

It's important to note that the values in the array are not unique. No index should appear in the result array more than once (in other words, `[4,0,1,1,5,2]` is not correct).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
ary.each_index.sort_by{|i| ary[i]}
# => [4, 0, 1, 3, 5, 2]
```

Comment: `to_a` can be removed. :)